# Programming example illustrating connection to sqlite database using vb.net under vs2012

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, connection, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for a simple example illustrating how to connect to an SQLite database using vb.net under VS2012. I already have downloaded and installed the SQLite dll from SQLite.org and have access to the SQLite namespace. The application needing access is being implemented in Visual Studio 2012 using XAML/VB.Net. An example including all import references which illustrated the process of connection, accessing and accessing an existing table would suffice.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed sqlite and accessed it via VB.net to open/create a database. I am looking for a simple example illustrating best practice which for example, opens a database, retrieves the structure and reads a few records. I have not found any online examples using VB.net and VS2012 (all seem to use C#).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    constr = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\latihan.db;"
    Dim cn As New SQLiteConnection(constr)
    Try
        cn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Dispose()
        cn = Nothing
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        dafill("select*from member order by nama", dt, cn)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    dt.Dispose()
    dt = Nothing
    cn.Close()
    cn.Dispose()
    cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add some details to your answer ?